# Prolog finding and removing predicate

Tags: prolog

I my have code:

```
locdiff([A|T], [A|_], T).
locdiff([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :-
    locdiff(T, L2, T2).
```

and when i test it with `locdiff([(a,1), (b,2), (b,3), (c,3), (c,4)], [(b,_)], L3)`, it only finds and removes one of the `[(b,_)]` which is `(b,2)`. I need it to find and remove both `(b,2)` and `(b,3)` or what ever the `[(b,_)]` contains. can anyone help me with what i have missed?

Comment: You're stopping at the first match. You need to keep searching until you hit the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a technical complication that's worth to note if you follow larsman' hint, that I would implement straight in this way

```
locdiff([], _, []).
locdiff([A|T], [A|_], R) :-
    !, locdiff(T, [A|_], R).
locdiff([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :-
    locdiff(T, L2, T2).
```

with this

```
?- locdiff([(a,1), (b,2), (b,3), (c,3), (c,4)], [(b,_)], L3).
L3 = [ (a, 1), (b, 3), (c, 3), (c, 4)].
```

you can see that the first instance is removed, and the last. That's because the first match *binds* the anonymous variable, and then forbids following matchings, except the last `(b,_)`

Then a completed procedure would read

```
locdiff([], _, []).
locdiff([H|T], [A|_], R) :-
    \+ \+ H = A,  % double negation allows matching without binding
    !, locdiff(T, [A|_], R).
locdiff([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :-
    locdiff(T, L2, T2).
```

now the outcome is what you are requiring.

Alternatively, you need to be more precise in pattern matching, avoiding undue binding

```
locdiff([], _, []).
locdiff([(A,_)|T], [(A,_)|_], R) :-
    !, locdiff(T, [(A,_)|_], R).
locdiff([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :-
    locdiff(T, L2, T2).

?- locdiff([(a,1), (b,2), (b,3), (c,3), (c,4)], [(b,_)], L3).
L3 = [ (a, 1), (c, 3), (c, 4)].
```

Please note that some library has specific functionality, like [exclude](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)/3 in SWI-Prolog, but still you need attention to avoid bindings:

```
eq([(E,_)|_], (E,_)).
locdiff(L, E, R) :-
  exclude(eq(E), L, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something loke that :

```
locdiff([], _, []).

locdiff([(b,_)|T], [(b,_)], T1) :-
    !, locdiff(T, [(b,_)], T1).

locdiff([H|T], L2, [H|T2]) :-
    locdiff(T, L2, T2).
```

But why do you write [A| _] if there is only one element in the list ?

[EDIT] I forgot the ! in the second rule